# make batch script copy by size AND a given amount

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make my script which copies only files above 3KB from a folder to another copy only 20 files not all

```
for /r "downloads" %F in (*.mp4) do @if %~zF geq 3000 move "%F" "test"
```

this works but it copies all files. I found solutions for nested for loops but all those solutions also affect ALL files.

Is there even a way to copy only 20 files from the downloads folder above 3KB with windows batch script?. The file order or the name don't really matter, just 20 files above 3KB, in my case I work with short logo videos.

Any solution is appreciated!
Sincerely
Gram

Comment: For starters, you are not running that code from a batch script. If you only want to copy twenty files why haven't you attempted to implement a counter and then break the loop with a goto command when the counter is equal to 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Squashman in the comment, you just need to add a counter. Note, this is `batch-file` format and I had to double up on the `%`:

```
@echo off & set cnt=1
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /R "downloads" %%F in ("*.mp4") do (
    Rem # if count is less than 21 and if file is larger than 3KB, move it and increment count by 1
    if !cnt! lss 21 if %%~zF geq 3000 move "%%~F" "test" && set /a cnt+=1
)
```

I have added some `rem`arks to the code to explain some of it. To find out more about what was done you can open. Just so you under stand the `if` statements. Both if's needs to return true else it will not move the file. So if the count is 21 or more it will stop processing files and it will also skip any files less than 3KB, as you already know.

To read up on `delayedexpansion` see `set /?` from `cmd` as well as `setlocal /?` and `for /?`.